# dividing $\binom{n-m-1}{k}$ by $\binom{n-1}{k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

for $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $m<n$, is there a closed form for this division? $\frac{\binom{n-m-1}{k}}{
\binom{n-1}{k}}$.

I ended up with $\frac{(n-m-1)!}{(-nk+mk+k)!}\times \frac{(-nk+k)!}{(n-1)!}$ and couldn't simplify it more. The case where $m=1$ I remember I found it $1-\frac{k}{n-1}$.

Comment: It seems you might find useful to check the definition of the binomial coefficients since the formula you suggest is way offbase.

Comment: @Did do you mean this one $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ ?

Comment: [What else?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQ4h_vDq0Hs)

Comment: @Did how about being specific instead of sending me to a blocked youtube in Canada. I applied that one and got to this point after removing $k!$ from both terms.

Comment: Sorry for the link, what about [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfyeXrdZZ1o)? Anyway, I WAS specific, thank you, and the mystery is how you reached these $(-nk+mk+k)!$ and $(-nk+k)!$... things. Care to explain?

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the formula: $k!(n-k)!\neq (kn-k^2)!$

Comment: @N74 I miscalculated the term $(n-m-1-k)!$ thanks for being helpful anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arithmetic after cancelling the factors of $k!$ seems to have gone astray.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\binom{n-m-1}k}{\binom{n-1}k}&=\frac{(n-m-1)!k!(n-1-k)!}{k!(n-m-1-k)!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(n-m-1)!(n-1-k)!}{(n-m-1-k)!(n-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(n-m-1)^{\underline k}}{(n-1)^{\underline k}}\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{n-m-i}{n-i}\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^k\left(1-\frac{m}{n-i}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Here $x^{\underline k}=x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-k+1)$ is a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).